# How to hide the verbose of "find" command in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu-13.04

I executed following command:

`find . name "myfile.txt"`

but this shows verbose information.

How to unshow this verbose ?

Comment: Pipe it to `grep` or `awk` or refine arguments for `find`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch How to pipe it with grep ?

Comment: @jkbkot verbose means it shows the directory and files through which it is searching the target file, i dont want this on terminal

Comment: read a good [shell tutorial](http://linuxcommand.org/learning_the_shell.php), then the [Advanced Bash scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Comment: correct command is: find . -name myfile.txt

Comment: Maybe you mean that it prints some errors. Try running it like this: `find . -name myfile.txt 2> /dev/null`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use following command

```
find . -name "myfile.txt" | grep myfile.txt
```